# Projects logo reset after new navigation update. How to put them back?

Tags: image, azure-devops, project

After changing my whole visualstudio space to the new navigation none of my project have image/logo anymore. They have the default first letter of project name. How to place back the logos on each project? I can't find it in the settings anymore.
Thanks for all the help :D

Comment: Are you talking about local Visual Studio or vsts?

Comment: I will answer as soon as i get my hands on a computer.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

For **new navigation mode**, this should be a bug or featured not delivered. You could submit a ticket in  [VSTS Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html), TFS PM and Admin will kindly help you there.

---

If you are talking about change the project image on VSTS. See the section "Custom Project image on Project description page" in our release notes at [Streamlined code and work items search – VSTS Sprint 124 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/2017/oct-06-vsts):

> VSTS has allowed you to upload a custom image for your Project (and
>   default team) for some time. However, this image was only visible on
>   the settings page. With this update, you will see the customized image
>   on the description page, which helps to give a unique identity to a
>   Project. If not customized, you will see an auto-generated image based
>   on the Project's name.

You could simply change the logo picture in **Settings--Overview--Project Profile**, click on the image. A popup will open allowing you to change it.

[image]

Comment: I tried going to Project Details in the new navigation but nothing happens when clicking on the image.

https://imgur.com/xW9rdx5

Comment: @Adrian Sorry for ignoring the  new navigation,  after change to this mode, I could reproduce your issue, got the same result as you. For **new navigation mode**, this should be a bug or featured not delivered. You could submit a ticket in  VSTS Developer Community, TFS PM and Admin will kindly help you there. Have update the answer.

Comment: I submited a ticket but still I have no answer. Thank you for all your help.